# Java Concert Hall OOP design

Tags: java, oop

I want to make a `Booking` class to book concert tickets. A `ConcertHall` class has 2 different seats, namely VIP and Regular. I've chosen `Seat[][]` as my data structure, where a `Seat` class contains `seat_number:String` and `preference:String`. Now, the VIP and Regular seats have a different capacity. Let's say the VIP's capacity is 10x5 seats and the Regular's capacity is 50x100 seats. The seats corresponding to both VIP and Regular also have Left, Center, and Right preferences.

The problem with my current design is I have so many redundant code . Let's say a user wants to book a concert ticket, he/she will call the method: `book("VIP", "Mary", "Center")`. This is what my design and book method look like:

```
class Booking
{
    private ConcertHall A;

    public Booking(String name)
    {
        A = new ConcertHall(name);
    }

    public boolean book(String serviceClass, String name, String preference)
    {
        Seat seat = find(serviceClass, preference)

        if(seat != null) 
        {
            assignSeat(seat, name);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

class ConcertHall
{
    private Seat[][] VIP;
    private Seat[][] Regular;

    public Seat findSeat(String serviceClass, String preference)
    {
        if(serviceClass.equals("VIP"))
        {
            // query VIP array
        }
        else if(serviceClass.equals("Regular"))
        {
            // query Regular array
        }
    }

    public boolean assignSeat(Seat seat, String name)
    {
        if(serviceClass.equals("VIP"))
        {
            // query VIP array
        }
        else if(serviceClass.equals("Regular"))
        {
            // query Regular array
        }
    }
}
```

There's already a problem here, namely for almost every method in `ConcertHall`, I have to do 2 identical checking for the VIP class and Regular class. Now I'm stuck. My code looks long and stupid because of the 2 identical checking.

===================================update===================================
I forgot to mention, there's an additional requirement. I have to keep track of the seats' position. Let's say a group of people want to book concert tickets, we have to find available seats in the same row. So, a HashMap wouldn't work here I think.

Comment: class is a reserved keyword... Anyway, maybe you should be using something like an enum instead of a string to determine the type?

Comment: @Paul_R Sorry. I changed it. Yes, enum is a good idea, I'll use it.

Comment: How would you specify which seat is `Left`, `Center` or `Right`?  `Left` relative to what? `Right` relative to what?...`Left` of someone maybe? But who?

Comment: "I've chosen `Seat[][]` as my data structure" Poor choice. You don't want to rely on the magic knowledge that `Seat[0]` is regular seating and `Seat[1]` isVIP seating, or the other way round, whatever it is. You should have `Seat[] regularSeats = new Seat[...]` and `Seat[] vipSeats = new Seat[...]`, where you can fill in your own dimensions.

Comment: You could also add the location information to the Seat object rather than tracking location via position in an array.

Comment: @Smac89 Sorry I wasn't clear, it would be something like 1/3 of the number of columns would be left, another 1/3 would be center and so on. So, in the VIP class, it would be 3 4 3 left center right. The preference information would be stored as a Seat's instance variable.

Comment: @EJP actually, that's what I did. Did you look at my `ConcertHall`'s instance members? I had `private Seat[][] VIP;` and `private Seat[][] Regular;` Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor out the identical array checking code into a method of its own and then pass it the correct lookup array. Something like

```
public Seat findSeat(String serviceClass, String preference)
{
    if(serviceClass.equals("VIP"))
    {
        return findSeatIn(VIP, preference);
    }
    else if(serviceClass.equals("Regular"))
    {
        return findSeatIn(Regular, preference);
    }
}

public Seat findSeatIn(Seat[][] seatArray, String preference)
{
     // query seatArray for preference
}
```

Then repeat this with `assignSeat()` and `assignSeatIn()`.

Also, `findSeat()` should ideally be `findSeats()` returning a list of seats matching a user's preference. The user should then be a able to choose one s/he likes the most, which should then be assigned by `assignSeat()`. Just a thought.

Comment: This is actually a good solution. I didn't know we could pass an instance member to an instance method before.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a Map in your `ConcertHall`. In your check just do a get on map, query and assign. So you can do something like this

```
class ConcertHall{
    private Map<String, Seat[][]> seatMap;

    public Seat findSeat(String serviceClass, String preference){   
        Seat[][] seats = seatMap.get(serviceClass);
        //query on seats    
    }
```

To use this, you need to put the seats in map appropriately. moreover you can use enum for the values like `VIP` and `Regular`

Comment: One you get the 2d array, you can loop through and find out which ones are empty, isnt it?

Comment: All other code will remain as before, there wont be any change if you use HashMap. it ll be a map of String, Seat[][],

Comment: I cringe when I see map being used like that. It's like bringing an elephant into a small room. What about splitting the method into 2 methods? `findSeatVip`, `findSeatReg`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that there is room (if I may say so) for an additional class that would represent individual regions of the hall; say:

```
class Zone {
    Seat[][] seats;

    public Zone(int rows, int columns) {
        seats = new Seat[rows][columns];
    }

    public Seat findSeat(String preference) {
        ...
    }

    public boolean assignSeat(Seat seat, String name) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This class could be sub-classed if different service classes would required a different behavior.

The ConcertHall class could be simpler:

```
class ConcertHall{
    private Map<String, Zone> zoneMap = new HashMap<String, Zone>();
    {
        zoneMap.put("VIP", new Zone(5,10));
        zoneMap.put("Regular", new Zone(50,100));
    }

    public Seat findSeat(String serviceClass, String preference) {
        return zoneMap.get(serviceClass).findSeat(preference);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a good initial design in order to get anywhere with oop. Here is an alternate implementation you might want to consider:

```
class Booking {

    public Booking(String personName, Seat seat) {
        ...
    }

    // getter and setters...blah blah
}
```

---

```
class ConcertHall {

    // Making it protected allows for easy subclassing
    protected List<Booking> vipSeating;
    protected List<Booking> regularSeating;    

    public ConcertHall(String name, int capVip, int capReg) {
        vip = new ArrayList<>();
        regular = new ArrayList<>();

        // initialise capacity, etc
    }

    public void addVipBooking(Booking b) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {

        // If there is room, add the person, else throw an exception
    }

    public void addRegularBooking(Booking b) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {

        // If there is room, add the person, else throw an exception
    }

    public boolean vipIsFull() {
        // is the vip section full??
    }

    public boolean regularIsFull() {
        // is the regular section full??
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good. It's actually similar to Ravi Thapliyal's solution.